# HTML input textbox onChange not working

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, onchange

This is what I have:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function toggle() {
        if (this.value=='1') {
            document.getElementById('dbOn').style.visibility='visible';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('dbOn').style.visibility='hidden';
            document.getElementById('dbOff').checked='checked';
        }
    }
</script>

<form action="index" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="iterations" value="1" onChange="toggle()" >

    <input type="radio" name="db" value="OFF" checked="checked" id="dbOff" >OFF<br>
    <input type="radio" name="db" value="ON" id="dbOn" >ON
</form>
```

The idea is that you will only be allowed to write to the database if you are doing one iteration. Otherwise, I want the "ON" option to become disabled or disappear and for OFF to be checked automatically.

So far, I have tried onChange, onKeyUp and onKeyPress, but none of them appear to work. Any idea what is wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: When setting the `checked` property, use a boolean - `true`/`false`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to your element when calling the function.

```
onchange="toggle(this)"
```

You'll also need a variable for the value in your function:

```
function toggle(element) {
        if (element.value=='1') {
  ...

}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/axxCH/1/

Comment: That doesn't fix it though, because `toggle` doesn't define any parameters :)

Comment: Of course, how stupid of me. I was using 'this' but forgot to pass the reference. Thank you.